# Auto create Twitter account when user signs up with my site?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Is there a way through the Twitter API to, when a user creates an account on my site, to automatically create a twitter account for that user in the background?  I guess my question is: Is there a way to create new twitter accounts via their API?

Answer (score 1):

No. You could however use a OpenID/OAuth combo to route them there when they sign-on, but I don't think you could automatically create an account for them masked behind your login logic. Even if you could, some might even badge it questionable ethics.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Hmmm... I wonder if there is a way to route them to the sign-up and capture their new account info in a callback... I was hoping for something more seemless than telling them to go to twitter, create an account, then come back to my site and either sign-in with it or enter the twitter info manually into their user profile...

Comment: That is what OpenID is for; allow your users to login with their Twitter account, Facebook account, Google, etc. Send the request to the provider's API, and they kick you back a token when the user has signed on. OAuth takes it a step further in that it allows you to ask the provider for privileges (the user must approve) on the account -- (ex. OpenId to authenticate a login with a Facebook, and then OAuth to gain authorization to interact with Facebook programaticaly as the user for instance to post to their wall or read their profile, etc.)